# Prevent LVM creating dm-X devices

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, lvm, device-mapper

Was wondering if it's possible to stop LVM on RHEL7 creating symlinks of /dev/dm-X to rootvg?

I'm using my RHEL hosts to connect to SAN LUNs, and prefer to have /dev/dm-X only mapped to multipath devices.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/dm-*` devices belong to the device-mapper subsystem, and since it is the underlying mechanism that is used not only by both LVM and multipathing, but also by disk encryption and some forms of software RAID, that is not really possible.

Run `dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname` to see all the things device-mapper is currently involved in on your system, if you're curious.

Comment: thanks. Isn't there a conf to tell it to create only for multipath devices?